# Text in the input is cut of vertically in safari

Tags: css, input, text, mobile-safari, vertical-alignment

I have a problem. The dots in the input type of password is cut, I can see only the half as in the screenshot. The point is that is not aligned vertically  neither in chrome or safari. But in chrome it at least visible.[image of the input with dots visible in half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIDYb.jpg)

```
<div class="input">
        <p>Password:</p>
        <div>
            <input type="password" class="button" id="password" name="password">
            <button type="submit" value="password" class="button">Enter</button>
        </div>
     </div>
```

the style

```
input[type=password] {
    font-family: modern_dos_8x8regular;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #7c7c7c;
    background-color: transparent;
    line-height: normal;
}

input[type=password]:after {
    line-height: normal;
}
```

I tried to line-height to normal but it doesn't seem to work and i have to put it more than 100% the line-height property, like to see the full dots, the only problem it's make input more larger and i don't want it. I don't want neither to use a negative padding coz it will also set in the chrome or other browser

Comment: Are you sure the default password dots displayed by the browser are supported in the font file? It seems the dots inside [Modern DOS 8x8 Font](https://fonts2u.com/modern-dos-8x8.font) I checked are just two (squared) pixels side by side (character value D 46). From your image it looks like the browser tries to display the default dots (rounded), ignoring the `font-family`.